# With the Google Analytics API, I is it better to do one query that returns many results or multiple queries that return a small number of results?

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics

At the moment I have an API query that is of the form

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
        'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
        'start-date': lastNDays(14),
        'end-date': lastNDays(0),
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
        'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
        'filters': 'ga:pagePath=~/fl/' + searchCats[i]
    }).execute(handlePagePathReportingResults);
```

I have a for loop that loops over the elements of searchCats and I am performing multiple API queries each returning a relatively small number of results (about 100).

However, I could instead use a loop to construct the query using OR statements

```
'filters': 'ga:pagePath=~/fl/' + searchCats[0] + '|/fl/' + searchCats[1] + |/fl/' + searchCats[2]
```

and so on, constructing one single query that returns a huge number of results (several thousand).

Which method is preferable? Is it preferable to perform one single query with a huge number of results, or many queries that return a small number?

Edit: I found that by concatenating the string by '|', I ran into the 128 maximum character limit of a regular expression. Instead, I concatenated multiple filters:

```
searchCatString = searchCatString + ',ga:pagePath=~' + searchCatUrl;
```

Comment: Basically, making one query with a big result is faster than a lots of queries with small results. But I don't what the concatenation of "OR" filters means in terms of report creation time. This could be a limitation and/or a bottleneck. Issuing a lots of requests in a short time may also lead to QUOTA_EXCEEDED errors on GA. Probably a mix: chunks of concatenated filters?

Comment: That's a very good point, I should probably test for that. Chunks of concatenated filters are a good idea! Thank you

Comment: Do you really need the filter? Performance-wise, it might be best to filter the results locally. It depends on how many search cats there are in total and how many you want to query.

Comment: Dude, reword your title. Keep it short and sweet :)

Answer (score 0):

**mortenalbring**,

I am not sure if there is any right answer to your question. It depends on what gives you the results you need:

- If it is speed, one big query might be better.
- If it is accuracy, the opposite approach will probably be better as it could help you avoid sampling.

Keep in mind however, there are some [limits for the reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/limits-quotas#discovery):

- 50,000 requests per project per day – [can be increased](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/limits-quotas#additional_quota)
- 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP.

Comment: Queries also can be increased from the console